# Execute ruby code in a link in Haml

Tags: ruby, haml

I want to have a "delete user" link in a normal Activerecord table, but I can't figure out how to wrangle the inline ruby in haml.

I have this:

```
   %tbody
    - @users.each do |user|
      %tr
        %td= user.name
        %td= user.login
        %td
          %a
            %img{:src => '../images/delete.png', :title => 'Delete user'}
```

How do I make the

```
- user.destroy
```

be a clickable link in Haml?

Comment: @James answer is correct. 

You can't have `user.destroy` method assigned to a html link. The only thing you can do is to put `user.destroy` method inside an action in a controller, and create a link that calls this method. @James answer shows standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want

```
%tbody
 - @users.each do |user|
   %tr
     %td= user.name
     %td= user.login
     %td
       = link_to image_tag('delete.png', :title => "Delete #{user}"), user_path(user), :method => :delete)
```

See [`ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper#link_to`](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M002452)

Or, if you're not using `ActionPack`,

```
%tbody
  - @users.each do |user|
    %tr
      %td= user.name
      %td= user.login
      %td
        %a{:href => "/users/#{user.id}?_method=delete"}
          %img{:src => '/images/delete.png', :title => "Delete #{user}"}
```

Comment: I'm using Sinatra.  Is there a way to do it without "link_to" and "image_tag"?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good tip on handling inline Ruby in HAML. It even allows you to have punctuation (notice the "!") after links (meaning it's *truly* inline).

From the [HAML FAQ](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.FAQ.html):

If you’re inserting something that’s generated by a helper, like a link, then it’s even easier:

```
%p== I like #{link_to 'chocolate', 'http://franschocolates.com'}!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- @users.each do |user|
  = link_to user_path(user) do
    = image_tag 'delete.png', :title => 'Delete user'
```